# In Django admin to truncate the number of characters for an field

Tags: django, django-admin

I want in Django admin to truncate the number of characters for a field.

For example, for:

```
list_display = ('description')
```

I want to show only the first 20 characters.

Comment: You can use custom methods for `list_display`, so write one that truncates the field. (You can use the `truncatechars` template filter for that if you like.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method to do that for example:

```
def get_description(self):
       return self.description [:20]
 get_description.short_description = "Description"
```

And you define 
list_display=('get_description')

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

In your model or admin class, define a method like this:

```py
def get_description(self):
     return self.description [:20]
get_description.short_description="Description"
```

And in your admin class:

```py
list_display='get_description',
```